# Javascript jQuery dom data api architecture

Tags: jquery

I have a question towards design of my application, it is a big project that contains the following example javascripts:

- modal.js (contains a jQuery plugin for modal forms)
- tooltip.js (contains a jQuery plugin for tooltips)
- textbox.js (contains a jQuery plugin for textboxes, placeholders etc.)

Would it hurt performance if I would use data-api to set up my whole javascript ui, so I would loop through all elements with this code and initialize a plugin if needed:

```
$.each('[data-trigger="modal"]', function(a, b){
  // Do plugin code here $(this).modal()
});

$.each('[data-textbox="^*"]', function(a, b){
  // Do plugin code here $(this).textbox()
});

$.each('[data-tooltip="hello, I am a tooltip"]', function(a, b){
  // Do plugin code here $(this).tooltip()
});
```

The other option would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#modal-create-account-trigger').modal();
  $('#tb-username').textbox();
  $('#tb-password').textbox();
  $('#tb-fullname').textbox();
});
```

I prefer the .each solution, so we can control it all fully in the HTML, how ever I know this is bad for performance, how bad is it, and are there alternatives?

Thanks alot for reading.

Comment: You can do `$("*").each` and check the data in a single selection and a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to use #ID selectors due to huge performance gain.

Comment: The page would have to be massive for there to be any noticable slowness with the data selectors. And if the page is that massive, loading the page will take forever in the first place.

Comment: @Esailija it's enough for the user if he uses IE6/7, which has problems with those selectors even on a small websites.

Comment: I don't think so, yes they're slow but not so slow that you cannot use these selectors once per page load. Maybe if he tried to do this in a mousemove handler, you'd have a point.

Comment: @Esailija well it all depends, what you are trying to accomplish. We don't know what is his target. He asked if it would hurt performance - it would. He might also use $('*').each() if he wants, but still people don't use it due to performance issues. I don't understand downvoting then since I replied his question.

Comment: First off, [screw IE6](http://ie6countdown.com).  Secondly, there's very, *very* little that's "always better", and performance is not the only thing worth caring about. If you need a bunch of elements operated on, whether getting them all by ID is faster or not, using some other selector tends to make life easier. For example, `$('[data-trigger="modal"]').modal();` as opposed to `$('#modal1').modal(); $('#modal2').modal(); /* etc */`. The first "just works", if the HTML's right -- while with the other, you have to remember to add the element to a list (and will probably forget at least once).